# Body tag does not render. ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'am working on small ASP.NET MVC project and I got an weird behaviour. At the point the project differs from ASP.NET MVC default template only by css stylesheets. The body tag is completely empty. Here you can see the master page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" />
    </title>

    <link href="<%: ResolveUrl("~/Content/Site.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="<%: ResolveUrl("~/Content/ObscuraUI.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="page">

        <div id="header">
            <div id="title">
                <h1>Obscura.com</h1>
            </div>            

            <div id="logindisplay">
                <% Html.RenderPartial("LogOnUserControl"); %>
            </div>

            <div id="menucontainer">

                <ul id="menu">
                    <li class="ui-corners-all" ><%: Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")%></li>
                    <li class="ui-corners-all" ><%: Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")%></li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="main">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />

            <div id="footer">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the home controller index view:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Home Page
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2><%: ViewData["Message"] %></h2>
    <p>
        To learn more about ASP.NET MVC visit <a href="http://asp.net/mvc" title="ASP.NET MVC Website">http://asp.net/mvc</a>.
    </p>
    <img src="../../Content/Images/Design/blackpony1440.jpg" alt="" class="protectedContent" />
</asp:Content>
```

I've looked through the generated html with firebug - the head is rendered correctly, but the body tag is completely empty but view initial source shows the correct html. I tried to throw an exception in index view and i got  the error page. I have no useful warnings while building project. but when i commented this line

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" />
```

everything was rendered well.

I thought of some script failure, but if I import just an empty file i get the empty screen. Why does it work this way ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You shouldn't use self-closing tags (`<tag/>`) for `<script>` tags. Doing that will make crazy things happen, as you have observed. You need to use this instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: +1 for this answer, which logic would never suggest! I had this happen to me in the past and lost a few hairs before I tried this solution on a lark, and voila!

Comment: I would love to know why you have to do this! As far as I know this isn't just some IE-specific weirdness. Obviously with a script tag you can have the actual script code between the opening and closing tags, but would it really be that hard to get browsers to support the self-closing tag as well?